# Printing array indices with the corresponding value in Python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, indexing

I have a problem in printing array indices with the value I want to find. I'm getting just the first indices and then not the others.

I have tried with the np.where function but It won't work so I had to make a loop manually.

Here's the code:

```py
g = 0.34
while g <= 0.97: 
        idx = []
        for i in range (0, y2.size):
            if y2[i] == g:
                idx.append(i)
        print(idx)
        g = g + 0.01
```

This is what I have:

```
[92, 376]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
.....
```

The array has 500 values from 0.34 to 0.97.
Same output with np.where(y2 == g) without the loop.

Comment: What is `y2` in your case? Is it a typical list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into `float` inaccuracies. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) post that deals specifically with that issue. In short, this is what happens in your code:

```
>>>g = 0.34
>>>g = g + 0.01
>>>g
Out: 0.35000000000000003
```

The result `0.35000000000000003` will no longer evaluate to `true` if compared with `0.35`. Try using `np.isclose` instead, as it deals with these minor inaccuracies:

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>g = 0.34
>>>g = g + 0.01
>>>g==0.35
Out: False
>>>np.isclose(g,0.35)
Out: True
```

You can even use it in combination with `np.where` to get your original approach to work:

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>g = 0.34
>>>y2 = np.array([0.37, 0.38, 0.37, 0.35, 0.34, 0.34])
>>>np.where(np.isclose(y2,g))
Out: (array([4, 5], dtype=int64),)
>>>g = g + 0.01
>>>np.where(np.isclose(y2,g))
Out: (array([3], dtype=int64),)
```